# PHP Form Posting Worked Yesteday But Not Today

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a form that up to yesterday was working with post to insert the form data into mysql table. Today it all stopped working and I changed nothing. This is driving me crazy.

Allot of the answers provided on line are based on correcting incorrect code. My code is correct, at least i think it is. It all worked fine after I wrote it and used it for several days. Then one day it just stopped working.

My post code is as follows.

```
<?php
include 'quality_module_connect.php';

// Don't forget to properly escape your values before you send them to DB
// to prevent SQL injection attacks

echo "<p>Content variables $_POST is:</p>";
print_r($_POST);


$field1 = $mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['field1']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO test(test)
        VALUES ('$field1')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

The results are that nothing is getting posted into the mysql table and I get no error message. When I insert with an insert statement without using post it all works fine.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Can you check your server error logs?

Comment: you want to remove `$`, use the proper function name `mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['field1']);`, not like you do now `$mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['field1']);
`

Comment: turn on error chjecking\display you have several.

Comment: The `mysqli_real_escape_string` in a procedural call requires a connection. So you have at least two issues. You should really use a prepared statement though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and it was not in the code, at least I do not think it was. I was opening the form using a hypelink with target="_blank"in the hyperlink statment so that it would open on a new tab. For some reason the new tab requirements with target="_blank" was causing the POST to be empty. Once I got rid of that everything is back to normal and fine. It would be nice to understand why.